# Discord bot not running

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, I am creating a discord bot and yesterday it just stopped running. So I was looking here and someone said to handle errors. With this so I tried it.

```
bot.on('error', (e) => console.error(e));
bot.on('warning', (e) => console.warn(e));
bot.on('debug', (e) => console.info(e));
```

And now I get this

```
Preparing to connect to the gateway...
[WS => Manager] Fetched Gateway Information
    URL: wss://gateway.discord.gg
    Recommended Shards: 1
[WS => Manager] Session Limit Information
    Total: 1000
    Remaining: 1000
[WS => Manager] Spawning shards: 0
[WS => Shard 0] [CONNECT]
    Gateway    : wss://gateway.discord.gg/
    Version    : 6
    Encoding   : json
    Compression: none
[WS => Shard 0] Setting a HELLO timeout for 20s.
[WS => Shard 0] [CLOSE]
    Event Code: 1006
    Clean     : false
    Reason    : No reason received
[WS => Shard 0] Clearing the HELLO timeout.
[WS => Shard 0] WS State: CLOSED
[WS => Shard 0] Failed to connect to the gateway, requeueing...
[WS => Manager] Shard Queue Size: 1; continuing in 5 seconds...
[WS => Manager] Session Limit Information
    Total: 1000
    Remaining: 1000
[WS => Shard 0] [CONNECT]
    Gateway    : wss://gateway.discord.gg/
    Version    : 6
    Encoding   : json
    Compression: none
[WS => Shard 0] Setting a HELLO timeout for 20s.
[WS => Shard 0] [CLOSE]
    Event Code: 1006
    Clean     : false
    Reason    : No reason received
[WS => Shard 0] Clearing the HELLO timeout.
[WS => Shard 0] WS State: CLOSED
[WS => Shard 0] Failed to connect to the gateway, requeueing...
[WS => Manager] Shard Queue Size: 1; continuing in 5 seconds...
```

In my terminal, and the bot is still not running.
Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the code of your bot, please provide more details

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you're having is listed in the console directly. You are setting the shards to spawn as 0, or not spawning any at all. This is shown in the console here:

```
[WS => Manager] Spawning shards: 0
```

To fix this, I'd recommend following [this guide](https://discordjs.guide/sharding/#how-does-sharding-work), which covers what, how, and when to shard. And, if you do decide to start sharding using the guide, take note of how many shards Discord recommends. You can find this amount in the console. Currently, this appears to be 1, as shown here:

```
[WS => Manager] Fetched Gateway Information
    URL: wss://gateway.discord.gg
    Recommended Shards: 1
```

Comment: I tried this and now I get “launched shard 0” and later I get “ (node:13) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [SHARDING_READY_TIMEOUT]: Shard 0's Client took too long to become ready.” so it still doesn’t start.